# Unexpected token on TypeScript component name

Tags: typescript, eslintrc

I'm having this Syntax error in my TypeScript component but I don't know why I'm having this error. Can you guys help me?

```
SyntaxError: src/components/client.ts: Unexpected token (15:11)

  13 | 
  14 | class Client {
> 15 |     public PostTweet({ tweet, response_string, odd_string }: { tweet: tweetInterface; response_string: string; odd_string: string; }): void {    
     |            ^
  16 |         console.log(`Respondendo ao tweet: ${tweet.id_str}`)
  17 | 
  18 |         var res = {
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

Comment: How are you compiling this code? Because the code looks fine, it might be a problem with your configuration.

Comment: I really don't know where is the problem in there... I'll figure out if it is coming from my tsconfig. Thanks for the support!

Comment: Pay attention to the `module` and `target` properties inside `compilerOptions`. The former will create the JavaScript file with the passed module syntax, while the latter changes the JavaScript version you are compiling to.